# WinForms application hangs following control invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, invoke, freeze

I'm running a WinForms app on 8 x virtual machines for testing.  Very rarely I'm seeing an application hang with a stack trace like the following.

I can see that, on some mystery control, an Invoke was required to avoid a cross-thread access (several controls could apply here), but I don't know what the application is `WaitOne`ing for.

This is the only thread in the parallel stack.

Is there an obvious clue in this call stack that might identify the issue as a common one?  I have read this article on the [Mysterious Hang](http://www.ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html) and I'm wondering if that could be what I'm seeing.

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle waitHandle = {System.Threading.ManualResetEvent})   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control caller, System.Delegate method, object[] args, bool synchronous) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate method, object[] args) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback d, object state)  Unknown
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke(bool checkFinalization = true, object[] args = {object[2]})    Unknown
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.RaiseEvent(bool checkFinalization = true, object key = {object}, object[] args = {object[2]})   Unknown
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanged(int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)    Unknown
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc(System.IntPtr hWnd = 131348, int msg = 8218, System.IntPtr wParam = 0, System.IntPtr lParam = 128232104) Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason = -1, int pvLoopData = 0) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {app.CustomApplicationContext})  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
    app.exe!app.Program.Main(string[] args) Unknown
```

Comment: Do you have `Invoke` anywhere in your code?  If so change it to `BeginInvoke()`.  The former can lead to a _deadlock_ and is generally harmful to kittens

Comment: @MickyD yes, actually I have both.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the problem go away when you change your code to **only** use `BeginInvoke()`?

Comment: @MickyD I haven't yet found a reliable way to reproduce the hang, so I can't yet say.

Comment: Maybe if you put your computer in a box and don't look at it? Darn quantum mechanics :P

Comment: @MickyD I think at this point I'd rather shoot it through two slits.